# Spring Boot and Thymeleaf: update database without refreshing page

Tags: ajax, database, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have an app showing listings, and I would like the user to be able to click a checkbox in order to "check" a particular listing as seen.

I have managed to do this if I refresh the page, but the issue is that with that solution I need to query the database to get back my "listings" each time a user "checks" a listing.

I think that with Ajax I should be able to update the particular listing object in the database without refreshing the whole page, and thus without querying the database for all the "listing" objects.

I have tried with the following code, but the Ajax function either is not called, or is not working, as my controller is not being called when I tick the checkbox:

Controller:

```
    @PostMapping({"/{id}/check", "Check Listing"})
    public void checkListing(@PathVariable("id") long id) {

        // update listing

    }
```

Checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" th:onclick="|checkedListing('${listing.id}')|"/>
<div id="successMessage" style="display:none;"> Listing successfully updated! </div>
```

Ajax function:

```
    function checkedListing(listingId) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "/" + listingId + "/check",
            success: function () {
                $("#successMessage").show();
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Could you please tell me what I do wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try making your ajax script thymleaf readable as

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
 /*<![CDATA[*/
   //here goes your ajax function
 /*]]>*/
</script>
```

Apart from that i assume you have controller method `public void checkListing(@PathVariable("id") long id)` in class `@RestController`

Comment: Thank you, I have added the code you mentioned in the script, and also I have moved the checkListing function to a new controller with annotation @RestController, but it is still not working... I am starting to wonder whether using ajax is a good idea, as I am not querying data, I am just updating the object and no data is returned...